# setInterval function does not work in Vue template

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, electron, setinterval

I am trying to call a function by using `setInterval` in a Vue object method, but it doesn't work.

I use a click event to call `login()` method

```html
<!--login.vue-->
<div ref="login_btn" class="login-btn btn" :style="btnLoadingSyle" 
@click="!isBtnLoading && login()">
     {{isBtnLoading ? 'Logining...' : 'Login'}}
</div>
```

then in `login()` I try to do this

```
//login.vue
login: function(event) {
            var that = this;

            if (this.checkInput()) {
                console.log(this.username + ' ' + this.password);
            } else {
                return;
            }

            this.isBtnLoading = true;
            this.btnLoadingSyle = {
                'background-color': "#515151",
                'color': "#ffffff"
            }

            var buf = Buffer.from(`${this.username} ${this.password}`);
            var count = 0;

            console.log("begin");
            this.timer = setInterval(() => {
                console.log("interval");
            }, 1000);
        },
```

then I mount this Vue template to a div in index.html

```
//index.html
<script>
...
const login = new Vue(Login).$mount('#login');
...
</script>
```

Then I use `npm start` to start my **electron** application, but the `setInterval()` completely doen't work when I input username and password and click.

In developer console, I try to read the `login.timer` and this is the result

```
> console.log(login.timer)
  VM257:1 null
< undefined
  login.vue:185 user 12345
  login.vue:199 begin
> console.log(login.timer)
  VM260:1 Timeout {…}
< undefined
```

It can be seen that befor I click the `div` I can't read the `timer`, but after I clicked, `timer` get the value from setInterval and `login()` looks work well, but I can't see any output every second.

`setInerval` works correctly in `index.html`

I am really confused about this problem and looking forward to get some ideas.

Thanks in advance.

---

*Edit*

Finally I find the reason probably is the scope

I just move

```js
import { setInterval, clearInterval, setTimeout } from "timers";
```

from `login.vue` to `index.html`
and it works.

Thanks guys.

Comment: Try using a lamba function, arrow functions have different behaviors. And change this.timer for that.timer.

Comment: `but I can't see any output every second.` What's you expect to see?

Comment: What is `Buffer`? If it's [this `Buffer`](https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html), that's not something typically available in the browser

Comment: Commenting out the `Buffer` line, I cannot reproduce this ~ https://jsfiddle.net/s30aeojg/. With the `Buffer` line, I get _"[Vue warn]: Error in v-on handler: "ReferenceError: Buffer is not defined"_

Comment: Actually, this is a electron application and `Buffer` is a nodejs API, I prapare to use a UDP socket `send()` method in `setInterval ` originally. To describe the problem easily, I use `console.log("interval")`

Comment: Oh right, sorry. I missed the tag. In any case, barring any errors (which you would probably see), I can't reproduce this